# MSP430F5529 USB communication drivers refuse to install correctly

Tags: embedded, msp430, texas-instruments

I am learning how to do USB communication with the MSP430F5529 Launchpad and trying to upload the CDC 1 LEDonOff Example from the MSP430 USB Developers Package provided by TI.

I am also following [this guide](http://fiona.dmcs.pl/~pzajac/pliki/SMwZW/Examples_Guide_MSP430_USB.pdf) specifically section 2.5.3 but when I plug in my launchpad I see the MSP Application UART and MSP Debug Interface but the third (MSP430-USB Example) doesn't show up under Other Devices with the yellow "bang", instead it shows up as "Unknown Device" under the USB Controllers Tab of device manager.

I tried right  clicking it and manually installing the drivers by navigating to the USB_Config folder of the example I was on, but it doesn't install, instead windows says it already has installed the most up-to-date drivers.

This makes it impossible to use any USB communication examples because this occurs on every example I have tried.

How do I force the computer to install the right drivers and recolonize the device as the USB Example device?

EDIT: I discovered a strange symptom, the drivers install properly (manually) when I flash the device and try to run it outside of a debug session (just connected to the PC from USB) and the program runs as intended connected to my terminal program on my computer, but when I try to run it inside a debug session it will not install the device properly (even if I never set any breaks, just open debug session and hit run), it always shows up as "unknown device" in debug session, even now - after I have installed the drivers and windows remembers it outside debug session - it only works outside of debug session and shows up as "unknown device" inside a session.

Comment: You need manually install the USB driver or you failed to flash your device, these are the main possibillities.

Comment: i discovered a symptom, the drivers install properly (manually) when I flash the device and try to run it outside of a debug session (just connected to the PC from USB), but when i try to run it inside a debug session it will not install the device properly (even if i never set any breaks, just open debug session and hit run.

Comment: When you're in a debug session, is the code actually running?

Comment: i step through it, it seems to be running, i put in some LED toggle statements in it and those work in debug.

Comment: @Aaron Sure the LED will blink, but your USB will not be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, I got what your problem. Your launchpad only have 1 USB connector compare to a Launchpad like  [this](http://www.ti.com/tool/ek-tm4c123gxl). When you are running a debug session, the bus is converted to UART to talk with the FTDI chip and the programming MCU therefore you cannot run a USB application at the same time with the example TI give you. When you just connect your launchpad, Window do a enumaration of your board and therefore the LP is detected as USB device and the application work fine. So in fact the example are working. If you want to debug & use the usb bus at the same time, it will require a lot of work, because you will have to develop code that share the bus alternatively between code composer and the USB application.

Comment: this makes so much sense. Thanks for the explanation, i guess im going to have to use the good ol' 'print statements to screen' debugging method when i need to debug applications that use the usb port.

Comment: i've discovered that if i start the debugger and hit the run button immediately without any breakpoints it will occasionally work, but if i ever hit hault or make a break point or anything it stops working (even if i remove the breakpoint or resume from hault). is this because the debugger isn't activated until there is a break or command?

Comment: @Aaron For that kind of precise on the internal function of code composer, I would recommend you visit TI forums in the code composer section

Comment: @Aaron The simplest option right now is to "manually" check and debug your board more than using the debugger.

Comment: yes i think thats the only option i have really